# How to refresh PrimeFaces image by javascript

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I am working with primefaces.  I need to write a java script function that can reload an image component. the function will be called by an applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this.I write it here in case somebody has the same question.
I used

```
<p:ajax event="click" update="image" />
```

And in javascript i fired a click event for the parent component. Please let me know if there are more effective way to do this.